# ping request cannot find raspberrypi.mshome.net address

Tags: raspbian, putty, ping

i have problem to find my RPI address.. currently just connect RPI using my laptop monitor.

i cannot find the current IP address for my PI using command prompt in windows7.

i have try to ping it by typing it with ping raspberrypi.mshome.net but the feedback ping request could not find host raspberrypi.mshome.net

any solution please share here.

Comment: What makes you think `ping raspberrypi.mshome.net` would work?

Comment: i have try many ways to connect my pi to my laptop... just this way i could share my internet into it...

Comment: How does the RasPi get an ip address? Is there a DHCP server running on your network? How do you connect the laptop monitor to the RasPi? Please address me with @Ingo, otherwise I won't see your reply.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to hit it by the IP address - there are ways to get that.

#### Through the Pi

Type in `ifconfig` and you will see your network details.  If you are connected through ethernet, it will probably be called `eth0`.  A wireless card will be called `wlan0`

#### Through Windows

Run CMD and type in `arp -a` to get all ip addresses that have previously connected with your network - however, this will not give the names of anything, so you'll have to narrow it down after that.  Furthermore, if the Raspberry Pi has not linked with the network and cached within the last five minutes, the IP will not be listed, so it is not a completely accurate solution.

I also found a nifty program that is (as far as I know) free.  [It's called Advanced IP Scanner and is located here.](https://www.advanced-ip-scanner.com/)

Generally my method of VNC'ing into my pi when it isn't attached to the screen is this:

- Make sure the pi is on a network and plugged in
- Run Advanced IP Scanner
- Log into it.

Comment: You write "*type in arp -a to get all ip addresses attached to your network*". This is not true. You only get the content of the arp cache with ip addresses that the device has connected in the last 5 minutes. If you haven't connected to the RasPi before you will not find it in the arp cache. B.t.w. MS Window$ is not an issue on Raspberry Pi.

Comment: `arp -a` doesn't need admin rights.

Comment: That scanner presumably shows "Raspberry Pi Foundation" based on the MAC address, but if not and ssh is running, you can narrow things down by scanning for an open port 22.